# How should I ensure all my (`.deb`) application's assets are cleaned up when it's uninstalled?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, deb

I'm creating a package for an application that installs a *lot* of assets when it first runs. It's looking like they'll have to live in `/var/lib/<myapp>`, which is fine. However, because these files aren't part of the original package, dpkg/apt doesn't know to delete them when it's removed. Is there some way to automate this?

I have seen it suggested that I put `rm -rf /var/lib/<myapp>` in the `postrm` script, but this doesn't seem to play nicely when I install the package over itself (it removes the directory when I don't want it to). Surely there's a built-in way to handle this, in the `deb` format?

Comment: If they were installed using `dpkg` or `apt-get`, then `sudo apt-get autoremove' should remove any auto-installed packages that are no longer used

Comment: Perhaps this `rm -rf /var/lib/<myapp>/*` will work better. The dir remains. Or let the `deb` package know about them so it can remove them

Comment: How can I let it know about files that aren't in the package?